# How to validate input field on change and show the message to the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, validationmessage

I have input field where user should enter System ID. After user enters System ID validation should be triggered. If System ID is valid, ajax request is sent to the server. If System ID is invalid, user should see the message. I use JQuery with Bootstrap 3.3.7 for this project. Here is example of my code:

```js
$('#system_id').on('change', getInfo);

function getInfo(e) {
  var fldObj = $(this),
    fldVal = fldObj.val();

  if (fldVal.length > 0 && fldVal.length <= 8 && Number.isInteger(Number(fldObj.val()))) {
    //Send Ajax Request
    console.log('Send request for System ID: ' + fldVal);
  } else {
    // Show message to the user.
    if (fldVal.length === 0) {
      fldObj.parent().removeClass('has-error has-feedback');
      $('#symbol-error').remove();
    } else {
      console.log('Invalid System ID');
      fldObj.parent().addClass('has-error has-feedback').append('<span id="symbol-error" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="system_id">System ID:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="system_id" id="system_id" value="" placeholder="Enter System ID">
  </div>
</div>
```

So far my logic works fine, I'm checking if user input value is integer and if it's in range between 1 and 8. I would like to display the message inside of the input field with alerts (bootstrap 3) if possible. If anyone know how to do this or if there is a better method for this please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: [Google bootstrap, alert](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bootstrap%2C+alert&t=ffsb&ia=web)  brings up [Bootstrap alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/).

Comment: @Taplar do you know how alert can be displayed inside of the input field?

Comment: What do you mean inside the input field?

Comment: Input border will be red, background color and text. So user can see when the id is invalid or valid.

Comment: So you want to change the input value to some message?

Comment: Yes, if it's invalid. If it's valid then just turn the the value to green color.

Comment: [jQuery css](https://api.jquery.com/css) to change borderColor, color and backgroundColor, and [jQuery val](https://api.jquery.com/val) to change the input value

Comment: @Taplar You can see my updated snippet. I found the way to show the symbol and color of the input field. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the script after the line 
console.log('Invalid System ID'):

```
  fldObj.parent().addClass('has-error has-feedback');
  $('#system_id').val('Invalid System ID');
```

The first line will color the input. 
The second line will insert your message.